# Improve loop by using mutate function

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr

I have a data frame called `result` which looks like that.

| lat | lng | Night |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41.60701 | 1.000831 | 2019-06-19 |
| 41.98151 | 1.973059 | 2020-04-11 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Basically, I whoul add 4 columns. One column for the time of sun set, the second for the sun rise, the third for the duration of the night in hour and finally the fourth for the sampling effort (I juste add the time buff to the duration of the night). I managed to do this by using a loop in the following code (unsing suncalc package for the `getSunlightTimes`).

```
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
library("reshape")
library("data.table")
library("stringr")
library("tidyr")
library("ineq")
library("suncalc")

library(suncalc)
time_buff <- 0.30
posta <- ls()
sorti <- ls()
night_hours <- ls()
temp <- result
for (i in 1:dim(temp)[1]) {
  lat <- temp$lat[i]
  long <- temp$lng[i]
  sset <- as.Date(temp$Night[i])
  sris <- sset + 1
  Tsset <- getSunlightTimes(sset, lat, long,
    keep = c("sunrise", "sunset"), tz = "UTC"
  )$sunset
  Tsris <- getSunlightTimes(sris, lat, long,
    keep = c("sunrise", "sunset"), tz = "UTC"
  )$sunrise
  posta[i] <- Tsset
  sorti[i] <- Tsris
  night_hours[i] <- round(as.numeric(Tsris - Tsset), 2)
}


# fetch results
temp$sun_set <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(unlist(posta)),
  origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"
)
temp$sun_rise <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(unlist(sorti)),
  origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"
)
temp$night_hours <- as.numeric(unlist(night_hours))
temp$night_effort <- as.numeric(temp$night_hours) + (time_buff * 2)

result <- temp
```

But it take very long time to run. So, I would know if there is an other simplest way to do that, using for example the mutate function from dplyr package instead of using a loop ?

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data.

Comment: like provide a sample of my real data ?

Comment: yeah, only two rows would be sufficient. And what package is `getSunlightTimes` from?

Comment: suncalc package and ok thanks I will complete the data frame

Comment: it's done. Is it ok ? or something is missing ?

Comment: @barthdufau if your date is in `22-06-2000`, then the `as.Date` needs `format` argument

Comment: sorry I replace in the data with the right format @akrum

Comment: @barthdufau with dplyr, you can use rowwise i.e. `data %>% mutate(sset = as.Date(Night),  sris = sset + 1) %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Tsset = getSunlightTimes(sset, lat, lng,  keep ="sunset", tz = "UTC")$sunset, Tsris = getSunlightTimes(sris, lat, lng,  keep ="sunrise", tz = "UTC")$sunrise) %>% ungroup` (it may not be that fast though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic calculation can be done in tidyverse with `rowwise` - i.e. `getSunlightTimes` is not vectorized for the `lat`, `long` so we have to provide only a single value at a time.  If there are duplicates for 'lat', 'long', instead of `rowwise`, may be better to do `group_by(lat, lng)` and then use `first(lat)`, `first(lng)` in the `getSunlightTimes` call

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(sset = as.Date(Night),  sris = sset + 1) %>% 
  mutate(Tsset = getSunlightTimes(sset, lat, lng,  keep ="sunset",
   tz = "UTC")$sunset,
  Tsris = getSunlightTimes(sris, lat, lng,  keep ="sunrise", 
   tz = "UTC")$sunrise) %>%
 ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
    lat   lng Night      sset       sris       Tsset               Tsris              
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <date>     <date>     <dttm>              <dttm>             
1  41.6  1.00 2019-06-19 2019-06-19 2019-06-20 2019-06-19 19:34:19 2019-06-20 04:22:55
2  42.0  1.97 2020-04-11 2020-04-11 2020-04-12 2020-04-11 18:29:30 2020-04-12 05:17:10
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(lat = c(41.60701, 41.98151), lng = c(1.000831, 
1.973059), Night = c("2019-06-19", "2020-04-11")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: when I run this code the cosonle said : Error in .buildData(date = date, lat = lat, lon = lon, data = data) :  'lat' must be a unique element. Use 'data' for multiple 'lat'

Comment: @barthdufau there wasa a typo.  if you add `rowwise` as in the update, it should work

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

We don't need to use a `group_by` or `rowwise`. Reading `?getSunlightTimes` tells us to use `data` as an alternative if we have multiple coordinates:

> date : Date. Single or multiple Date. YYYY-MM-DD
>
> lat  : numeric. Single latitude
>
> lon  : numeric. Single longitude
>
> data : data.frame. Alternative to use date, lat, lon for passing multiple coordinates
>
> keep : character. Vector of variables to keep. See Details
>
> tz :> character. Timezone of results

So we can pass the dataframe as a whole to the function, but need to have the right names for the columns. See below;

```
result %>% 
  mutate(night = as.Date(night)) %>% 
  mutate(sunset = getSunlightTimes(data = transmute(., 
                                          date = night, lat = lat, lon = long), 
                                   keep = "sunset")$sunset,
         sunrise = getSunlightTimes(data = transmute(., 
                                           date = night + 1, lat = lat, lon = long), 
                                    keep = "sunrise")$sunrise,
         night_hr = as.numeric(round(difftime(sunrise, sunset, units = "hour"), 2)),
         night_effort = night_hr + (time_buff * 2))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>     lat   long night      sunset              sunrise             night_hr night_effort
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <date>     <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1  40.0  -75.2 2023-04-13 2023-04-13 23:37:13 2023-04-14 10:25:55     10.8         11.4
#> 2  34.1 -118.  2023-04-01 2023-04-02 02:14:19 2023-04-02 13:40:21     11.4         12.0
```

---

---

We can use `rowwise` instead of a loop. Or better, `group_by(lat, long)` and only pass the first lat and long for each group.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(suncalc)

result <- data.frame(lat = c(39.9526,34.0522), 
                     long = c(-75.1652, -118.243), 
                     night = c(mdy("4/13/2023"),mdy("4/01/2023")))
time_buff <- 0.3

result %>% 
  group_by(lat, long) %>% 
  mutate(sunset = getSunlightTimes(as.Date(night), lat[1], long[1])$sunset,
         sunrise = getSunlightTimes(as.Date(night) + 1, lat[1], long[1])$sunrise,
         night_hr = as.numeric(round(difftime(sunrise, sunset, units = "hour"), 2)),
         night_effort = night_hr + (time_buff * 2)) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>     lat   long night      sunset              sunrise             night_hr night_effort
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <date>     <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1  40.0  -75.2 2023-04-13 2023-04-13 23:37:13 2023-04-14 10:25:55     10.8         11.4
#> 2  34.1 -118.  2023-04-01 2023-04-02 02:14:19 2023-04-02 13:40:21     11.4         12.0
```

Comment: When I execute this code the console said : Error in .buildData(date = date, lat = lat, lon = lon, data = data) : 'lat' must be a unique element. Use 'data' for multiple 'lat'

Comment: @barthdufau you see that I have `rowwise`, right? That is actually important for this to work.

Comment: @barthdufau I added an alternative which does not need looping and is considerably faster.